# How to ignore one or more output bus pins for a module instantiation

Tags: syntax, system-verilog

I want to ignore one or more bits in an array argument for a module in SystemVerilog.

```
module x(in a, out [0:3] z);
...
endmodule

module tb;
  logic my_a;
  logic [1:3] my_z;
  // I want to stop having to do this next line:
  logic ignore_this_bit;
  x myx(.a(my_a), .z({ignore_this_bit, my_z}));
endmodule
```

What is the proper syntax to do this? I have been doing it just as shown above with a declaration of `ignore_this_bit` and simply never connecting to that net. But it seems there should be a simpler way. Something like just using a comma and no variable name in the arguments for the module instantiation or maybe using something like `1'bX` instead of an output argument bit, or something like that.

Is this affected by the fact that I am using big-endian bit ordering for the vectors here? (I hate it, but I am building code for an old CPU that uses that ordering and it's way easier to match my code to the existing than to fix it.)

This is a hard concept to search for, and I have tried. Does anyone have expertise that can help me know how to do this "the right way"? Thanks.

Comment: Yours is the perfect  way for doing it. There is no special syntax for ignoring bits of the output port.

Comment: Thanks Serge. I was afraid this would be the answer. Maybe you should put your answer in the form of an ANSWER to this question (separate post, not a comment here) so I can mark it as such.

Comment: I do wish there were less verbose syntax for doing this very common thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special way in verilog for ignoring bits of the output. So, your way of using concat with an unneeded variable is a good way for doing it (`{ignore_this_bit, my_z}`). Naming of this variable is important for readability reasons.

It is not affected by the range description order. It looks like you are ignoring the left-most bit. And the bits are always ordered in the same way, no matter how you describe the range:

```
bits:   0011
[3:0]:  3  0
[0:3]:  0  3
concat: {ign, 0, 1, 1};
```

The other way around is to use a variable big enough to connect to the output and then use its bits:

```
logic [1:3] my_z;
logic [0:3] their_z;
 x myx(.a(my_a), .z(their_z));
 assign my_z = their_z[1:3];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to do anything here. This should just work truncating the MSB z[0]

```
x myx(.a(my_a), .z(my_z));
```

Think of an output port as an implicit continuous assignment

```
assign my_z = myx.z;
```

But if the MSB is not the bit you want to ignore, there is no simple solution. You might want to look at the net `alias` feature.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the `alias` feature. It's something I have wanted. It doesn't help this issue much though.

Comment: Also, ignoring ANY of the bits in a bus is what I really need. I should have said that in my query. If I have a mux that drives eight outputs and I want to ignore three of them (in the middle) I have to declare a bunch of `logic` variables to do so. This is more painful than it should be.